# Show a chain is a composition series for a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> Consider the ring
>   $$
> R = 
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \mathbb{Q} & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
>  \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   as a left $R$-module over itself. I want to show that the following is a composition series
>   $$
>  0=\begin{pmatrix}
>   0 & 0 \\
>   0 & 0
>  \end{pmatrix}\subset
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   0 & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & 0
>  \end{pmatrix}\subset
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   0 & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
>  \end{pmatrix}\subset
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \mathbb{Q} & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
>  \end{pmatrix}=R
> $$
>   for $R$.

So I consider the quotients of the terms, for example $ \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{Q} & 0 \\
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
 \end{pmatrix} /  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
 \end{pmatrix}$. I see that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. Can I use this to show that the quotient is simple?

Similarly how can I do the same thing for the quotient  $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb{R} & 0
 \end{pmatrix} /  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Are you considering $R$ as *left* $R$-module or *right* $R$-module? Probably this does not make difference, but anyway...

Comment: As a left $R$-module. Apologies. I shall add it to the question now.

Comment: You say "isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$": I wonder: isomorphic *as what*?

Comment: As rings? Take $\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}\mapsto a $ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $ \begin{pmatrix}
>   \mathbb{Q} & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
>  \end{pmatrix} /  \begin{pmatrix}
>   0 & 0 \\
>   \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
>  \end{pmatrix}$. I see that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. Can I use this to show that the quotient is simple?

That alone is probably not a transparent enough explanation of why it is simple. You can, if you like, start with the fact it is isomorphic to $\begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb Q & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$ as a left $R$ module, and note that for any two nonzero elements $\begin{pmatrix}x & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}y & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, you can find $\begin{pmatrix}q & 0\\r&s\end{pmatrix}$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}q & 0\\r&s\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. (When a ring acts transitively on the nonzero elements of a module, that means it is simple.)

Similar logic holds for $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb R
 \end{pmatrix} /  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb R & 0
 \end{pmatrix}\cong\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0&\mathbb R
 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb{R} & 0
 \end{pmatrix} /  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}\cong \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  \mathbb R & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm afraid I haven't learned about a ring act on modules. Is there another way to show the simplicity of these quotients?
My ultimate goal is to show $R$ is left artinian and my aim was to show it has finite length and thus is left artinian (and left noetherian).

Comment: @lego323 The *definition* of a module is about a ring acting on a module... I rather think you *have* learned about it. I think, if you try it out, you'll agree it's a very simple approach. My claim is that given a left $R$ module $M$, then $M$ is simple iff for every nonzero choice of $x,y\in M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $rx=y$.

Comment: This direction $\implies$ is obvious. For the other direction, suppose $x$ was a nonzero element of a proper submodule $N$. Since $N$ is proper there's a $y\in M\setminus N$. But $y=rx$ for some $x$, so $y$ is actually in $N$, a contradiction. So there are no nontrivial submodules.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I was getting confused, apologies of course I've learned about it. Well that's rather neat. Thank you! You are a god with this kind of stuff, I appreciate your other work on here.

Comment: @lego323 That's saying too much, but nevertheless I'm glad to have helped in this case.